# keypress within time limit in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to reset a timer whenever any key has been pressed in session of bash. I would like this not to interrupt anything you're trying to do in the session but just reset the timer every keypress. All of the things I have found interrupt what you are doing. Thank you for suggestions. Any questions just ask and be patient I, unfortunately, might be a bit slow to the page.

Comment: A *specific* key or *any* key? You can catch signals (like SIGINT sent with ^C) with `trap`.

Comment: any keypress in this case. specific keys might be of use later but now all keys including modifiers. Also an example of the use of trap in this case and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really any "good" or "idiomatic" way to do this, unless I'm forgetting about something. But there are two ways you can "sort-of" do it:

Use a `while` loop and `read` with a timeout. Note that this uses some `bash`-specific extensions and is not portable to other shells. It may also not fit the logic of your code. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

timer=0
while :; do
    # Read one key with a timeout of 1 second
    read -s -t1 -n1 key

    [ "$key" = "a" ] && timer=0

    # Do some work here
    echo "key: $key, timer: $timer"

    timer=$(( $timer + 1))
done
```

Another downside of this is that `read` is waiting for 1 second.

---

Another option is to abuse signals. When you press some keys on the keyboard a signal is sent to the process; ^C sends `SIGINT`, ^Z sends `SIGSTP`, etc. You can catch or "trap" some of these signals with the `trap` command and run a command. It's a bit like exceptions in modern programming languages.

You can also send a signal with `kill(1)`. Also see `signal(7)`. Not all signals can be caught (some are caught by the terminal, such as ^S and ^Q, although you can disable this).

```
#!/bin/bash

timer=0

signal() {
    echo $timer
    # Allow quiting by pressing ^C twice in a row
    [ $timer -lt 2 ] && exit
    timer=0
}

# See trap -l for a full list.
trap signal SIGINT

while :; do
    echo "timer: $timer"
    timer=$(( $timer + 1))
    sleep 1
done
```

This doesn't have the delay and works for all shells. But has the obvious downside that it's limited to several control mappings. It's also something of an abuse of the signal feature.

If you want to do more than this, you should probably consider migrating to a "real" programming language.

Comment: the sig one is not what I want and the first one I need to try and implement. sorry just now I realize my earlier comment is misleading